# Jtable not showing results

Tags: jtable

## Jtable struggles

*please help im trying to display data from an ms access database but no *data is shown when i run the file.

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableD extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public TableD() {
        initComponents();


Vector columnNames = new Vector();
Vector data = new Vector();

try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection connect =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:cb1");

String sql = "Select * from tblbooks";
Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );

}
while (rs.next()) {
Vector row = new Vector(columns);
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
}
data.addElement( row );

}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println( e );
}
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

//JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
//getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

//JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
//getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        TableD frame = new TableD();
/*frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.pack();
frame.setTitle("Information Table");
frame.setVisible(true);*/


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableD().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I've also tried connecting Jtable to the database using the wizard but failed dismally as the jdbc:odbc driver URL couldnt be found.

Comment: You've got your database access in a try...catch block. Is it logging any errors?

Comment: no errors, just not returning anything

Comment: Might be seem like an obvious question, but is there anything in the database to return?

Comment: The next thing I would do is remove the try...catch block so that it can't fail silently. Let it crash, then at least it will give you the error if there is one.

Comment: yes there is data in the table.

Comment: No idea what to tell you.  There's a lot of moving parts in database access, especially when working with multiple layers to access a file. This is one of many reasons why dedicated database servers are favored over file based data stores. All I can suggest is... poke around.  Try to break it. Getting errors, even if they are unrelated to the specific problem, is way more helpful than a silent failure.  Try to query non-existent tables.  Move your access database file. Connect to a different type of ODBC source and try to get some data from it.

Comment: when i remove the try...catch block i get the following error "unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown..."

Comment: There you go! Looks like it's not finding your driver, if I had to guess by the exception name.  Now you can poke around and ask a more specific question.  I would open a new question and focus the code around that problem.